# Should I use shared preferences or stick with SQLite?

Tags: java, android

I've developed an android app that displays a letter for a user to draw, the user draws this and finds out if they're correct or incorrect and the app loops through the alphabet. I've handled users logging in and signing up by using SQLite. However I want a button "retrieve data" that when clicked will display all of the users and their stats. By stats I mean two integer values for each letter eg Correct_a and Incorrect_a etc.

This would mean creating 52 columns in the database, and I suppose I would have to retrieve the database data as a List or something. However I've seen snippets online of storing user data with shared preferences, but i'm completely unfamiliar with using shared preferences. I was just wondering if anybody could recommend the better approach: SQLite or shared preferences, and if anybody has a clear tutorial on using shared preferences in this way that would be great.

UPDATE: Here's my code for creating the database. When I check it in sqlite manager ID, USERNAME and PASSWORD are the only columns created. Do I need to initialise LETTER, isCorrect and inCorrect to add them or what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;

        public static final String isCorrect = "Correct";
        public static final String inCorrect = "Inorrect";
        // SQL Statement to create a new database.
        static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                     "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text, LETTER text" + isCorrect + inCorrect + "); ";
```

Comment: `52 columns in the database` no you don't. I'd recommend getting some basic SQL tutorials if you're not familiar with SQL.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd still need a column for each letter, then two rows for the integer value of correct drawings and incorrect drawings of the letters.

Comment: no you don't. You can store it in four columns: [id, key, is_correct, value]

Answer (score 0):

@Jay Using sqlite database is better than shared preferences and as explained by Lie Ryan, you  will only need 4 columns in the database. You can refer following tutorial   http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Thanks, I've been following that tutorial but I'm hitting a snag. I've created the table to only have the columns ID, Username, Password, letter, isCorrect, inCorrect. But when I pull the database and use sqlite manager on firefox to check if everything has created ok, I only have ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD. I'll edit my question post to show my code.

Comment: You must specify datatype for your columns and separate them with comma          static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                     "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text, LETTER text, " + isCorrect +" text, " + inCorrect  +" text ); ";